# Vue3 Production Mode for CDN implementation

Tags: vuejs3, cdn

I get the console message `You are running a development build of Vue. Make sure to use the production build (*.prod.js) when deploying for production.`

I'm not using a webpack or any other bundler, it's just a static page just pulling from a CDN:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@v3.1.1"></script>
```

just for context, we're instantiating Vue3 like this:

```
var vueApp = Vue.createApp({
  data() {return {display: 'Hello World'}},
}).mount('#vapp');
```

Is there a minimized production version of Vue3 I can pull instead of `vue@v3.1.1`?

Answer (score 18):

Instead of using
`https://unpkg.com/vue@v3.1.1` which resolves to `https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.1/dist/vue.global.js`

you can use `https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.1/dist/vue.global.prod.js`

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.1/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

Comment: Verify the Vue version by using the `console.log(Vue.version)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.global.prod.js` instead, it will redirect to latest version `vue.global.prod.js`.

```
// Example: 
// https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.global.prod.js
//
// If the latest version is 3.2.37,
// It will redirect to 
// `https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.prod.js`

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

##### NOTE:

It works with the same rule for `axios` CDN url.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```